# how to change emulator direction for both portrait and landscape?

Tags: android

I am use ctrl+f11 it will change the orientation of emulator.but the content of screen does not change.and also i created layout-port and layout-land folder also.. in my emulator does not change that orientation..

Is there is any other controls or code to do for that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, ensure that you have enabled the `Screen rotation` from the notification bar, then you can use these shortcuts :

<kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape backwards

<kbd>Ctrl+F12</kbd> Switch layout orientation portrait/landscape forwards

Comment: how to ensure screen rotation from notification bar? i'm using emulator as Google Nexus 7'inch and API level 19.. there is no options for rotate the screen..

Comment: I think in Google Nexus 7 , there's a widget that you have to drag it to the home screen in which you can enable the rotation screen option